# How Protective Is Allah over the muslims

Tags: allah, helping, protection

I believe Allah Is our only protector and the greatest one, but I've seen so many posts of how much he loves us.

I am In NO way doubting him, I Just want pieces from the Quran where Allah shows his protection over us, or how much he cares for us (JUST CURIOUS).

I apologize If this IS worded badly I have no bad Intentions asking this

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious answer from Holy Quran is stated in Surah Ar-ra'd, verse 11 ([13:11](https://quran.com/13/11)):

> لَهُ مُعَقِّبَاتٌ مِّن بَيْنِ يَدَيْهِ وَمِنْ خَلْفِهِ يَحْفَظُونَهُ مِنْ أَمْرِ اللَّهِ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يُغَيِّرُ مَا بِقَوْمٍ حَتَّىٰ يُغَيِّرُوا مَا بِأَنفُسِهِمْ ۗ وَإِذَا أَرَادَ اللَّهُ بِقَوْمٍ سُوءًا فَلَا مَرَدَّ لَهُ ۚ وَمَا لَهُم مِّن دُونِهِ مِن وَالٍ
>
> For each one are successive [angels] before and behind him who protect him by the decree of Allah . Indeed, Allah will not change the condition of a people until they change what is in themselves. And when Allah intends for a people ill, there is no repelling it. And there is not for them besides Him any patron.